# STM32F2 bootloader issue

Tags: arm, stm32, bootloader

I have write a bootloader to jump into my app.
First I have try with a simple blinky-led app  => I am able to jump into the app from the bootloader.

Now I want to jump into my real app. The app is working well alone but when I jump into it from my bootloader the app crash as soon as the interrupts are enabled, my jumping code :

```
__disable_irq();
 SCB->VTOR = (uint32_t)0x0800BA00;
 JumpAddress = *(__IO uint32_t*) (0X0800BA04);
 JumpToApplication = (pFunction) JumpAddress;
__set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*) 0X0800BA00);
 JumpToApplication();
```

I don't know what is wrong and why the activation of interruptions crash the app.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you jump to the application, you should deinitialize everything that you've initialized in the bootloader. If your bootloader uses USART with interrupts, you should disable this USART (for example using `RCC->AHBxRST`/`RCC->APBxRST` registers) and disable its interrupts. You should also jump to your application with interrupts enabled. Your application should get the chip just as it would be after a normal reset.

If your application uses this crap code from ST called SPL or HAL, then make sure that this code does *NOT* reset SCB->VTOR back to 0 or 0x8000000, because normally it does that in `SystemInit()`, which is called from `Reset_Handler()`, before `main()`.

BTW - are you absolutely sure about the address of your application? You usually put the application at the page boundary, while your code does not indicate that - `0x800ba00` (46.5kB) is pretty far from the closest page boundaries 32kB and 48kB...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have disabled all the peripheral and the associed interrupts. I also need to reset them as you suggest ? I have also reenable the general interrupts before jumping. In SystemInit() I have already set the VECT_TAB_OFFSET to 0xBA00. It still no work when the app activate the interrupts. Do you have any other idea ? Concerning the adress I'm sure that is the good one I write the linker app file to fit those adress.

Comment: @caius - you can instruct the linker to put your application at 0x800ba00, but be aware that flashing that application to that address will erase the memory from 0x8008000 (32kB). If it still does not work, then I guess you should try to debug your problem - verify the values of appropriate registers, see what exactly is a "crash" ("does not work as expected" or "jumps into hard fault" or sth else), and so on.

Comment: Well thanks again for your time. I will try to debug it but I'm not sure how to do it after jumping into the app. Concerning the adress I will erase from 0x8008000 as you suggest. To understand if I don't erase it what are the risks ?

Comment: @caius If you don't erase full page - from 0x8008000 to 0x800bfff - the application cannot be written there. Make sure your bootloader is not placed there. To debug the problem, just flash the application in any way you like and start the debugging session of the application (NOT the bootloader), but start it without flashing it at the same time. Flashing should be a separate step.

Comment: Ok, without the activation of interrupt in the app I'm able to jump in it and execute it so I guess the write of the app is not a problem but for safety I wil erase it first. My bootloader stop before the new page. Ok for the debugging but my application work well when I flash it and launch it without the boot. But I'm not sure with my IDE that the 2 steps are done separately I will check that.

Comment: @caius If activating the interrupts prevent you from jumping into the application, then I'd say that something is not deinitialized in the bootloader. But you have to debug that to know where the problem is - in the debugger, in the application, in the flashing, ... Either with debugger or at least with UART or a LED.

Comment: Well thank you Freddie ! After deactivation of the peripheral and their clock my app run well with interrupts working ! Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

set clock setting of boot code & application code same

Comment: this looks like a comment, not answer.